# Method call requires reference to assembly. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

Assembly A

```
class A {
    void SaveToDisk(); // Calls B.Extract
}
```

Assembly B

```
class B {
    static void Extract(); // References Ionic.Zip
}
```

The compiler is telling me that Assembly A requires a reference to Ionic.Zip as well, even though Assembly A has no references to any Types within Ionic.Zip in the SaveToDisk method. Why does the Ionic assembly need to be referenced in Assembly A?

Comment: Is it possible that B also has an overload `static void Extract(SomeTypeFromIonicZip param)`?

Comment: There is an overload with a ZipFile parameter. Will that cause this?

Comment: Maybe assembly `B` exposes types from assembly `C` somewhere else.

Comment: You are leaking types from Iconic.zip into your assembly metadata.  That is not obvious from the snippets, consider a decompiler if you have no idea how that happened.

Comment: It is the call to Extract that causes the problem. I am using instance methods and properties off of the same type and it is fine.

Comment: Yes, the overload is at fault. To select the correct overload, .NET needs a reference to Ionic.Zip to check whether there is, for example, an implicit conversion from SomeType to ZipFile.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll have to work around this. Thanks a lot!